# craft cms command line update to version 3.5.12.1 or greater fails

Tags: php, yii2, craftcms

I am running the following command to update craft cms:

```
php craft update craft
```

However upgrading to version 3.5.12.1 or greater fails with the following error:

```
Performing update with Composer ... done
Applying new migrations ... error: The command "'/var/www/craft' 'migrate/all' '--no-content'" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /var/www

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
Error: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given


Output:
```

The current version of craft that I am running is 3.3.19, and it's running in a docker, using the following composer.json:

```
. . .
 "require": {
    "aelvan/craft-cp-element-count": "^v1.0.1",
    "aelvan/imager": "v2.3.0",
    "aelvan/inlin": "^2.1",
    "aelvan/preparse-field": "v1.1.0",
    "am-impact/amcommand": "^3.1.4",
    "angellco/portal": "1.1.3",
    "angellco/spoon": "3.3.7",
    "charliedev/element-map": "^1.2",
    "charliedev/section-field": "^1.1.0",
    "craftcms/aws-s3": "1.2.5",
    "craftcms/cms": "3.3.19",
    "craftcms/feed-me": "4.1.2",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.4.0",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-inventory": "2.0.3",
    "doublesecretagency/craft-siteswitcher": "2.1.0",
    "ether/logs": "^3.0.3",
    "ether/sidebarentrytypes": "^1.0",
    "fruitstudios/linkit": "1.1.11",
    "hashtagerrors/user-initials-photo": "1.1.1",
    "lukeyouell/craft-queue-manager": "^1.1.0",
    "marionnewlevant/snitch": "3.0.0",
    "misterbk/mix": "^1.5",
    "mmikkel/child-me": "1.0.6",
    "mmikkel/cp-field-inspect": "1.0.7",
    "mmikkel/incognito-field": "1.1.1.1",
    "monachilada/craft-matrixtoolbar": "^1.0.6",
    "nfourtythree/entriessubset": "1.2.2",
    "nystudio107/craft-cookies": "^1.1",
    "nystudio107/craft-emptycoalesce": "1.0.6",
    "nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize": "1.6.4",
    "nystudio107/craft-minify": "^1.2.9",
    "nystudio107/craft-retour": "3.1.27",
    "nystudio107/craft-scripts": "^1.2.4",
    "nystudio107/craft-seomatic": "3.2.32",
    "nystudio107/craft-typogrify": "1.1.18",
    "nystudio107/craft-webperf": "1.0.14",
    "ostark/craft-async-queue": "2.0.0",
    "page-8/craft-manytomany": "1.0.2.2",
    "putyourlightson/craft-blitz": "2.3.4",
    "rias/craft-position-fieldtype": "^1.0.13",
    "rias/craft-width-fieldtype": "^1.0",
    "spicyweb/craft-embedded-assets": "2.1.1.1",
    "spicyweb/craft-fieldlabels": "1.1.7",
    "spicyweb/craft-neo": "2.5.7",
    "superbig/craft-entry-instructions": "1.0.6",
    "topshelfcraft/environment-label": "^3.1.5",
    "verbb/cp-nav": "^2.0.9",
    "verbb/default-dashboard": "^1.0",
    "verbb/expanded-singles": "^1.0.4",
    "verbb/field-manager": "2.1.0",
    "verbb/icon-picker": "1.0.10",
    "verbb/image-resizer": "2.0.6",
    "verbb/super-table": "2.3.0",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
    "wbrowar/craft-communicator": "^1.0",
    "wbrowar/guide": "2.1.2",
    "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0"
  },
  "repositories": {
    "element-map": {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "./plugins/element-map"
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\utilitiesmodule\\": "modules/utilitiesmodule/src/",
      "putyourlightson\\blitz\\drivers\\storage\\": "plugins/blitz-override"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "config": {
      "process-timeout": 0
    },
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.2.5"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "./craft migrate/all",
      "./craft clear-caches/all"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "./craft migrate/all",
      "./craft clear-caches/all"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried disabling plugins but that seems to make no difference. Also, I am not sure where the "'/var/www/craft' 'migrate/all' '--no-content'" command is even coming from since that seems to be slightly different command than what is in the composer.json.

When I try to run just the migration:

```
./craft migrate/all
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given'

in /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/UrlManager.php:222
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError()
#1 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/UrlManager.php(222): array_merge()
#2 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/src/Module.php(290): yii\web\UrlManager->addRules()
#3 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(333): yii\debug\Module->bootstrap()
#4 /var/www/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(61): yii\base\Application->bootstrap()
#5 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(279): craft\console\Application->bootstrap()
#6 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(125): yii\base\Application->init()
#7 /var/www/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(47): yii\console\Application->init()
#8 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\console\Application->init()
#9 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(212): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct()
#10 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(90): yii\base\Application->__construct()
#11 [internal function]: yii\console\Application->__construct()
#12 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(420): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()
#13 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\di\Container->build()
#14 /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get()
#15 /var/www/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(246): yii\BaseYii::createObject()
#16 /var/www/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php(51): require('/var/www/vendor...')
#17 /var/www/craft(21): require('/var/www/vendor...')
#18 {main}
```

It appears to be a bug in craft related to the UrlManager code, but if this is the case, I don't know why others have not seemed to experience it (I couldn't find anything about it in my searches)? Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be wrong?

Comment: It's asking for a second parameter. Probably thinking it's a migrate plugin. Have you tried using `php craft migrate/all` instead of ./?

Comment: @LordNeo so `php craft migrate/all` does return "Migrated up sucessfully." however subsequently running `php craft update craft` still returns the same error as I posted above?

Comment: Updating using the Control Panel itself shows any other info (other than "parameter 2 needed")?

Comment: @LordNeo I've tried updating through the control panel but kept getting 504s. I tried modifying various config files (php.ini, composer.json) to extend the timeout but no luck so far.

Comment: I'm going to asume you're using PHP 7.2 or later. Because from 3.6 it doesn't work with 7.0 anymore

Comment: yes `php --version` returns `PHP 7.4.9`

Comment: composer.json and config.platform.php also updated for the PHP version? Could you post the output of `php craft update` please? It should output the list of handlers

Comment: composer.json lists php as 7.2.5 and I can't find a config.platform.php in the project so I am not sure about that one. The output of `php craft update` is: `Error: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given`

Comment: try this `php -d allow_url_fopen=1 craft update`

Comment: Just as sidenote: Line 222 on "yii2/web/UrlManager.php" it's about "buildRules" and "addRules" maybe you could check your routing rules too and see if there's something that could cause error or maybe update yii2

Comment: That php command gives the same error, unfortunately.
Also, routing rules are in routes.php right? I checked and it looks ok
it's `return ['gql' => 'graphql/api'];`
When I looked at the craft UrlManager.php code, it _looks_ like _getRules() is returning null ($request->getIsConsoleRequest() is true), which a method in the yii base class is later throwing an exception on (because it's not [ ])
but if that's the case i don't know why no one else has run into this issue? So maybe i am misunderstanding?

Comment: I would try updating yii2 first, it's a weird issue and looks it doesn't have anything to do with craft. I also searched for similar issues, but all are related to laravel or pusher.

Comment: Thank you so much @LordNeo for your help, I was able to figure out a solution, which I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure out the issue. I had inherited the project and someone had added `'bootstrap' => ['debug']` to the config/php.app file, to enable the Yii debug toolbar. This debug module is calling addRules() on the UrlManager object, and craft code had set the rules field of this object to null instead of [ ]. When addRules() was called, array_merge() threw an exception on the null value (as it was expecting [ ] instead). This code path can be avoided entirely by removing the debug module.

TLDR; remove 'debug' module from config/php.app if you get an array_merge() exception in UrlManager.php when updating to craft 3.5.12.1 or greater.